# PDO... Am I doing it right?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So honestly, this is the first time I am working with PDO and Error Exceptions. I have gone thru manuals as well as different Q/As resolved here in past and came up with code that I am pretty satisfied with. But I really really need your opinion on this. I have built few functions that I normally use often in my projects.

Please note that right now I am doing a test project just intended to learn these 2 new things.

First of all, I am not a fan of OOP and have always preferred procedural programming type.

```
function _database_row($_table, $_id = 0, $_key = "id") {
    global $Database;

    if(is_object($Database)) {
        $Query  =   $Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$_table} WHERE {$_key} = :id");
        if($Query->execute(Array(":id" => $_id))) {
            $Query_Data =   $Query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($Query_Data)   >=  1) {
                if(count($Query_Data)   ==  1) {
                    return $Query_Data[0];
                }

                return $Query_Data;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Database Query Failure: ".$Query->errorInfo()[2]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

the above function is intended to fetch a row from `$_table` table with `$_id` (not necessarily an integer value).

1. Please note that `$_id` may (sometimes) be the only thing (for this function) that is fetched from `$_REQUEST`. By simply preparing the statement, am I totally secure from any SQL injection threat?
2. I couldn't find an alternative to mysql_num_rows() (I indeed found few PDO methods to use fetchColumn while using COUNT() in the query. But I didn't prefer it that way, so I want to know if I did it right?

also before people ask, let me explain that in above function I designed it so it returns the row directly whenever I am looking for a single one (it will always be the case when I use "id" as `$_key` because its PRIMARY auto_increment in database), while in rare cases I will also need multiple results :) this seems to be working fine, just need your opinions.

example of use:

```
_database_row("user", 14); // fetch me the user having id # 14
_database_row("products", 2); // fetch me the user having id # 14
_database_row("products", "enabled", "status"); // fetch me all products with status enabled
```

...sometimes during procedural programming, I wouldn't like those nasty "uncaught exception" errors, instead I will simply prefer a bool(false). So I did it like this:

```
function __database_row($_table, $_id = 0, $_key = "id") {
    try {
        return _database_row($_table, $_id, $_key);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(don't miss the use of another leading "_"). This also seems to be working perfectly fine, so what's your opinion here?

IMPORTANT:

1. what is the use of "PDOStatement::closeCursor" exactly? I did read the manual but I am quite confused as I can call my functions as many times as I want and still get the desired/expected results but never "closed the cursor"

now... ENOUGH WITH `SELECTS` AND `FETCHINGS` :) lets talk about `INSERTS`

so I made this function to add multiple products in a single script execution and quickly.

```
function _add_product($_name, $_price = 0) {
    global $Database;

    if(is_object($Database)) {
        $Query  =   $Database->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES (:name, :price)");
        $Query->execute(Array(":name" => $_name, ":price" => $_price));

        if($Query->rowCount()   >=  1) {    
            return $Database->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Database Query Failure: ".$Query->errorInfo()[2]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This also seems to be working perfectly fine, but can I really rely on the method I used to get the ID of latest insert?

Thank you all!

Comment: Why would using global variables somehow magically be "doing it right"? Therefore, answer is: **NO**

Comment: No, I daresay you’re not doing it right. It’s pretty much never a good idea to ignore exceptions from databases, and you also shouldn’t have to throw your own errors. Make sure to set `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` (or whatever it is). I’d also make it fetch objects by default, since you almost never want *dynamic* results.

Comment: Also, methods prefixed by two underscores are reserved by PHP.

Comment: @NobleUplift maybe you are right but it seems to be working.

Comment: @NobleUplift they're not reserved, but typically double-underscore methods have some magic functionality.  There are some such methods in PHP that are reserved like `__get`

Comment: whats wrong with global variables @teresko ?

Comment: Straight from the documentation: `Caution: PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical. It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on here, so I will try to answer specific questions and address some issues.

> I am not a fan of OOP

Note that just because code has objects doesn't mean that it is object oriented.  You can use PDO in a purely procedural style, and the presence of `->` does not make it OOP.  I wouldn't be scared of using PDO for this reason.  If it makes you feel any better, you could use the procedural style `mysqli` instead, but I personally prefer PDO.

---

> By simply preparing the statement, am I totally secure from any SQL injection threat?

No.

Consider `$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE col1 = $_POST[rightFromUser]")`.  This is a prepared statement, but it is still vulnerable to injection.  Injection vulnerability has more to do with the queries themselves.  If the statement is properly parameterized (e.g. you were using `?` instead of `$_POST`),  you would know longer be vulnerable.  Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM {$_table} WHERE {$_key} = :id
```

actually is vulnerable because it has variables in it that can be injected.  Although the *query* is vulnerable, it doesn't necessarily mean that the *code* is.  Perhaps you have a whitelist on the table and column names and they are checked before the function is called.  However the query is not portable by itself.  I would suggest avoiding variables in queries at all -- even for table/column names.  It's just a suggestion, though.

---

> I couldn't find an alternative to `mysql_num_rows()`

There isn't one.  Looking at the count of fetched results, using `SELECT COUNT` or looking at the table stats (for some engines) are surefire way to get the column count for `SELECT` statements.  Note that `PDOStatement::rowCount` does work for `SELECT` with *MySQL*.  **However**, it is not guaranteed to work with any database in particular [according to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).  I will say that I've never had a problem using it to get the selected row count with MySQL.

There are similar comments regarding [`PDO::lastInsertId`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).  I've never had a problem with that and MySQL either.

---

> let me explain that in above function I designed it so it returns the row directly whenever I am looking for a single one

I would advise against this because you have to know about this functionality when using the function.  It can be convenient at times, but I think it would be easier to handle the result of the function transparently.  That is to say, you should not have to inspect the return value to discover its type and figure out how to handle it.

---

> I wouldn't like those nasty "uncaught exception" errors

[Exception swallowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding) is bad.  You should allow exceptions to propagate and appropriately handle them.

Generally exceptions should not occur unless something catastrophic happens (MySQL error, unable to connect to the database, etc.)  These errors should be very rare in production unless something legitimately happens to the server.  You can display an error page to users, but at least make sure the exceptions are logged.  During development, you probably want the exceptions to be as loud as possible so you can figure out exactly what to debug.

I also think that names should be reasonably descriptive, so two functions named `__database_row` and `_database_row` are really confusing.

---

> IMPORTANT: what is the use of "PDOStatement::closeCursor" exactly?

I doubt you will have to use this, so don't worry too much about it.  Essentially it allows you to fetch from separate prepared statements in parallel.  For example:

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($query1);
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->fetch();
// You may need to do this before $stmt2->execute()
$stmt1->closeCursor();
$stmt2->fetch();
```

I could be wrong, but I don't think you need to do this for MySQL (i.e. you could call `execute` on both statements without calling `closeCursor`.

---

> can I really rely on the method I used to get the ID of latest insert?

PDO's documentation on this (above) seems to be more forgiving about it than it is about `rowCount` and `SELECT`.  I would use it with confidence for MySQL, but you can always just `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

---

## Am I doing it right?

This is a difficult question to answer because there are so many possible definitions of *right*.  Apparently your code is working and you are using PDO, so in a way you are.  I do have some criticisms:

```
global $Database;
```

This creates a reliance on the declaration of a global `$Database` variable earlier in the script.  Instead you should pass the database as an argument to the function.  If you are an OOP fan, you could also make the database a property of the class that had this function as a method.  In general you should avoid global state since it makes code harder to reuse and harder to test.

> the above function is intended to fetch a row from $_table table with $_id

Rather than create a generic function for querying like this, it is better to design your application in a way that will allow you to run queries that serve specific purposes.  I don't really see why you would want to select all columns for a table for a given ID.  This is not as useful as it seems.  Instead, you probably want to get specific columns from these tables, perhaps joined with other tables, to serve specific functions.

Comment: Thank you, these are the comments I really needed! but if you can get back to me on this: (1) in my _database_row() func, inside the query where $_table and $_key are used, they are totally safe as there values are hard coded in script (not fetched from _GET or _POST or any other way for website visitor to change them). therefore I used prepare for $_id alone. (2) That function is really handy in my script and lets me perform tasks faster, I know that there is a lot that could be done but what I have is sufficient for the purpose. Is that not good?

Comment: (3) how about using count($_Query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) to get number of total rows from a select query? it seems to be working fine now but can I rely on it for future? and yes I do need the num_rows :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your main problem is not OOP, but SQL.

To tell you truth, SQL is by no means a *silly key-value storage* you are taking it for. So, it makes your first function, that can be used only on too limited SQL subset, is totally useless.

Moreover, you are making a gibberish out of almost natural English of SQL. Compare these 2 sentences

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = ?
```

quite comprehensible - isn't it?

```
products! enabled! status!
```

HUH?

Not to mention that this function is prone to SQL injection. So, you just have to get rid of it. If you want a one-liner, you can make something like this

```
function db_row($sql, $data = array(), $mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    global $Database;

    $stmt = $Database->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt->fetch($mode);
}
```

to be called this way:

```
$row = db_row("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?",[14]);
```

Note that PDO is intelligent enough to report you errors without any intervention.  All you need is set it into exception mode.

Speaking of second function,  can be reviewed.

```
function _add_product($_name, $_price = 0)
{
    global $Database;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES (?,?)";
    $Database->prepare($sql)->execute(func_get_args());
    return $Database->lastInsertId();
}
```

is all you actually need.

> I couldn't find an alternative to mysql_num_rows()

You actually never needed it with mysql and would never need with PDO either

Comment: please define " too limited SQL subset"

Comment: ok I see... so suppose I am on a order checkout page, and I need to retrieve user, product, and payment method data from database. You are saying that I should use prepare/execute every time I have to?

because what I intended is like:

$user = _database_row("users", 100); // user ID i.e. 100 retrived from session.
$product = _database_row("products", 14); // product ID retrived from form that user submitted.
$payment_method = _database_row("payment_methods", 3); // also an option selected by members.

so basially $_id is the only foriegn value, rest are hard coded.

Comment: Please, all these details are so trifle. Are you writing your functions only for order checkout page? I suppose there will be dozens of pages, each with its distinct requirements and input data. So, consider more generalized usage of these functions than just one silly three-query-page.

Comment: I think I will stick with use of sill three-query function because thats what being used already and I am just upgrading mysql_query to PDO. So basically that function meets my demand :) I know there is alot could be done but can't like I can only use single match in WHERE query but its "OK" for me... I wanted opinion on if `$_id` is safe from SQL injections (other 2 can never be because they are not foriegn values).

Comment: I also did need mysql_num_rows alternative. Some times its needed, thats why it exists :) so basically:

IS count($Query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) a good alternative for mysql_num_rows?

Comment: No. You just *think* that you need the number, but in reality you don't. If you still need it - then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Let's say I'm running pagination... isn't using the number of rows returned a good method of easily discovering if a new page link will need to be created? Or, is this simply a matter of shunting the query results to an array and running a count() on that?

Comment: @Andrew especially if you are running pagination you don't need this function ever. Because you should NEVER select all the rows from table, but only amount that fits for one page.

Comment: @Andrew `$totalRows = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName ")->fetchColumn(); ` for number of rows in table

Comment: @David... how about number of rows in the table matching the WHERE query, and the query has foriegn variables vulnerable to injections?

Comment: @Mfaspk how about using prepared statements?